# How to make objective-c to c converter

Tags: objective-c, c, vala

I'm trying to make a source to source converter which translate objective-c code to c source code like valac(which translate vala to c code). I'm not sure if [this](http://pastebin.com/yVKFqfuU) is objective-c completely but that's how i want it, so it's kind of my own language.

in the start i thought i could just use `string.replace` but that won't work because one can just create something like this: `- (person)myperson {}`.

so i thought scanning the text char by char would do it but [my code](http://pastebin.com/1xVnTXnH) dosen't work for some reason. what is wrong? and can i find a better way of doing it(maybe using regex?). If this way of doing it is right, how can i then convert a `char[]` array to a string (on line 72)?

So how would i make a objc to c converter? All links and examples are appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I don't mean to discourage you, but you seem to be in way over your head. Before taking on such a task, you'll need to thoroughly understand some quite advanced concepts. Start simpler :)

Comment: To emphasize just how monumental this task is, I advise you read the dragon book first, by Aho & Ullman

Comment: hmmm i'm a little confused? i don't think it might be as hard as you say. The goal is to convert the the objc parts to c. like when my program sees something like `- (void)myfunc:(string) g {` then it will convert it to `void myfunc (string g){`. it's only the text conversion?

Comment: @user69969: `- (void)myfunc:(string) g` is more than `void myfunc (string g)`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LLVM has an [Objective-C rewriter and it is open source](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/RewriteObjC_8cpp_source.html).  Would be a good starting point.

This, btw, is a HUGE undertaking.